# Can I format decimal points even if user inputted whole number?

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to format a user's input into having 2 decimal places? For example the user inputted "12345" and in the system it will be formatted into "123.45". I tried using `number_format` but it didn't work.

Comment: what if user type 1234?? And did you try anything

Comment: does the number have to be in 2 decimal places?

Comment: not recommended, for example, if I input on your website, 10256, how you can tell what number I meant?

Comment: I tried. As I said i used number_format and read lots of questions here that talks about number_format and decimal places. But they all lead to the answer "12345.00". If the user typed 1234 I want to have "12.34" if its possible

Comment: Tried dividing?

Comment: @kerbholz thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to have your number in 2 decimal places. Try this one.

```
number_format($number / 100.0, 2, '.', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `number_format`.

Documentation:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

**Example:**

```
$number = 12345;

$format_number = number_format($number / 100, 2, '.', ''); // outcome: 123.45
```

A couple of other example with different outcome, so you get the idea behond `number_format`:

```
$number = 12345;

$first_format_number = number_format($number / 100, 2, '.', ''); // 123.45
$second_format_number = number_format($number / 100, 2, ',', '.'); // 123,45
$third_format_number = number_format($number / 100, 1, '.', ''); // 123.5
$forth_format_number = number_format($number / 100, 4, '.', ''); // 123.4500
```